# Arabic character in centos

Tags: linux, centos, arabic

I try to create folder with arabic character at centos linux..

For example when i type

```
 mkdir الاختبار
```

is working but when i try to view a folder using ls it's turn into question mark

i have another centos and but doesnt have this problem, already try to install arabic language

```
yum install "Arabic Support"
```

still not work for me and also try to install font

```
yum install dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
```

Does anybody have clue about this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `locale` to something that uses UTF-8. The default "C" locale doesn't support any non-ASCII characters. Try this for example:

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Alternatively you can force `ls` to print the file names without mangling (this will work assuming your terminal supports UTF-8):

```
ls --show-control-chars
```